# Searching for equal strings using strcmp

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp

I have a 2D array containing real words of the same length (dictionary). I also have a 2D array of strings (mostly rubbish, with some real words in there). I'm trying to find the real words in the second array by using strcmp. Once a real word is found (strcmp = 0), I want to copy that word into a new 2D string array called `actual_words` then print it.

However mine seems to just print `Words which are viable:` and no actual words ... no errors though.

All strings are null terminated.

```
void check_dictionary (char equal_length_dictionary[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH], char nextword[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH])

{
int arr, dict;
char actual_words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH];

printf("\nWords which are viable: \n");

for (dict = 0; equal_length_dictionary[dict][0] != '\0'; dict++)
{
//look through each word in dictionary
    for (arr = 0; nextword[arr][0] != '\0'; arr++) 
    //look through each word in the array
        {
                if ((strcmp(equal_length_dictionary[arr], nextword[arr])) == 0) 
                //test for differences between dictionary and word
                    {
                        strcpy(actual_words[arr], nextword[arr]); 
                        //if no differences, copy words
                        printf("%s ", actual_words[arr]);
                    }
        }
}     
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Are the words in the arrays null-terminated? (If not, you should use `strncmp` and `strncpy`)

Comment: @Finlandia_C Be careful with `strncpy` as it might not always zero terminate the string.

Comment: If the lists are large it would be faster to sort both lists and then make one pass through both looking for matches.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same index in the comparison for both arrays:

```
if ((strcmp(equal_length_dictionary[arr], nextword[arr])) == 0)
```

Array equal_length_dictionary should use index `dict` not `arr`.

Comment: Same as above, this still prints zero words out.

Comment: From the code you posted it is impossible to determine the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess it the comparison;

```
strcmp(equal_length_dictionary[arr], nextword[arr])
```

You use the same variable `arr` for both arrays. The first array should be indexed by `dict` I would guess:

```
strcmp(equal_length_dictionary[dict], nextword[arr])
```

Also, both strings needs to be zero-terminated or you would have *undefined behavior*. If the strings are not zero-terminated you need to use `strncmp` instead (or possibly `memcmp`).

Comment: This still prints zero words out. I have added that they are all null terminated strings in the main question.

Comment: @Finlandia_C It might be time to use a debugger, and step through the code line by line to see what happens and what the strings really are. Remember that `strcmp` is case-sensitive and that white-space in the strings are compared as well (and white-space includes tabs and also the newlines that e.g. `fgets` include in the strings it reads). Optionally print out both strings inside quotations to check that they are indeed equal.

Comment: I have used fscanf to read in the strings instead of fgets. Time to learn how to use a debugger I guess!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the words being compared I have one guess:
1. There are leading or trailing spaces you don't know about. Try printing out the strings with delimiters in the print statement so you can easily see if there are any spaces that need to be trimmed.